# trouble in getting nested object result from MongoDB to node environment via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Here I am trying to store some data to MongoDB with respect to the schema and data mentioned above. And also I can store the exact data with the code. But while trying to fetch I can't get the **name** of the user as it is in the object inside the result object.

**Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var sch = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new sch({
userid: Number,
name: {
    first: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    last: String
},
age: Number,
linkedin: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
        validator: function(text) {
            return text.indexOf('https://www.linkedin.com/') === 0;
        },
        message: 'LinkedIn must start with https://www.linkedin.com/'
    }
},
description: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**Example Data**

```
var Data = new User({
    userid: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
    name: {
        first: "foo",
        last: "bar"
      },
    age: 30,
    description: 'Backend Developer',
    linkedin: 'https://www.linkedin.com/End-Your-If-194251957252562/')};
```

**Storing data to mongo db**

```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Successfully connected');

        var User = **Data**;
    // Data is above mentioned hard coded one.

        User.save(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('User successfully saved.'); 
        });

    });
    mongoose.model('users', {name: String});
```

**MongoDB stored data**

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5b683e4b05c56f4e08662017"), "name" : { "first" : "foo", "last" : "bar" }, "userid" : 718, "age" : 30, "description" : "Backend Developer", "linkedin" : "https://www.linkedin.com/End-Your-If-194251957252562/", "__v" : 0 }
```

**code for trying to fetch saved data from mongo db via mongoose**

```
    app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
        mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
            res.send(users);
        })
    });
```

**result via mongoose not showing the name of the user**

```
    [{"_id":"5b683e4b05c56f4e08662017","userid":718,"age":30,"description":"Backend Developer","linkedin":"https://www.linkedin.com/End-Your-If-194251957252562/","__v":0}
```

please, anyone, help me to sort out this issue

Thanks,
Lavanya

Comment: Nothing seems to error. Paste your whole schema file, please.

Comment: I've edited my schema in the above post. Please have a look at it..

Comment: Schema looks ok. I was thinking that there must be something pre-function run that may exclude name.

Comment: `mongoose.model('users', {name: String});` Why? you should remove that line from `Storing data to mongo db`

Comment: Thanks! Issue resolved from my end. Mistakenly this line is placed.. (mongoose.model('users', {name: String}); )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the line is messing up something to your data.

```
mongoose.model('users', {name: String});
```

Please remove this.